# mySQL - add colors to individual names in query

Tags: mysql

I have table `PHYSICIANS` in `mySQL` that contains names of `Physicians`.

I would like to `asign specific colors` to each one of these Physicians.

I would like to make this dynamic because I will be doing this for multiple databases and Physician names are different and number of Physicians varies also.

I don't know any other way that manually entering Physician names and assigning colors to it, or below code.
Does anyone know of any other way?

These are colors I would like to use:

```
#FF0000,#800000,#FFFF00,#808000,#00FF00,#008000,#00FFFF,#008080,#0000FF,#000080,#FF00FF,#800080

SELECT PHYS_ID, color
from
(
    Select PHYS_ID
    From PHYSICIANS
    Where PHYS_ID != 0
    Order By PHYS_ID
) Physicians,

(
    SELECT '#FF0000' as color
UNION
    SELECT '#FFFF00'
UNION   
    SELECT '#808000'
UNION   
    SELECT '#00FF00'
UNION   
    SELECT '#008000'
UNION   
    SELECT '#00FFFF'
UNION   
    SELECT '#0000FF'
UNION   
    SELECT '#000080'
UNION   
    SELECT '#FF00FF'
UNION   
    SELECT '#800080'
    FROM DUAL
) colors
```

Comment: so put a `colors` field int your Physicians table and assign one of those colors to each record...

Comment: I can't manipulate table :( I have to do it in the query

Comment: Then put the field in a new table. With a key field, e.g. equal to PHYS_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you can't modify anything, then you could try using something like [`ELT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt)

```
SELECT PHYS_ID, ELT(MOD(PHYS_ID, N)+1, '#color1', '#color2', ...., '#colorN')
                                 ^----------------------------------------^
```

Basically, take the physician's ID, modulo the number of colors you have. e.g. for 5 colors:

```
id 3 mod 5 -> 3
id 30 mod 5 -> 0
id 31 mod 5 -> 1

ELT(3 + 1, ...) -> color4
ELT(0 + 1, ...) -> color1
ELT(1 + 1, ...) -> color2
```